# change image url on keydown left and right arrow

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

Im inserting image inside a div when page loads. Here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
namespace DanielaS
{
    public partial class ImageDisplay : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string photo = (string)Session["image"];
            Image image = new Image();                        
            image.Attributes.Add("class", "imgOne");
            image.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            image.Attributes.Add("id" , "img");
            image.ImageUrl = photo;         
            ImageDiv.Controls.Add(image);
        }

    }
}
```

Im passing the image url string with Session from previous page.All my images are in folder and are named 1.jpg , 2.jpg 3.jpg and so on.
What im trying to do is to change this image url when i press left or right arrow using Jquery.So if image displays for instance 19.jpg when i hit the left arrow i want to set this image url to 18.jpg and if right arrow is clicked set to 20.jpg im trying something like this :

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(this).keydown(function (e) {

                if (e.keyCode == 37)
                {
                     // var img_src = $("#img").attr("src");
                     //var Newimg_src = img_src name decremented by 1
                     // $("#img").attr("src" , Newimg_src);
                }
                else if (e.keyCode == 39)
                {
                    // var img_src = $("#img").attr("src");
                    //var Newimg_src = img_src name incremented by 1
                   // $("#img").attr("src" , Newimg_src);
                }

            }); 
        });
    </script>
```

I need to add If condition to know if the imageUrl is last in the folder aswell.To set the next to 1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't count the number of the files using jQuery, it is better done with PHP as below:

```
iterator_count(new DirectoryIterator('/images/'));
```

but if you know how many files there already are in the folder, you could just give it to a variable and use the code below:

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var currentImage=1;
        var maxImage=10; //let's say you only have 10 images in the folder
        $(document).keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 37)
            {
                if(currentImage!=1){
                    var currentImage--;
                    $("#img").attr("src" , 'images/'+currentImage+'.jpg');
                }
                else{
                    var currentImage=10;
                    $("#img").attr("src" , 'images/'+currentImage+'.jpg');
                }
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == 39)
            {
                if(currentImage!=maxImage){
                    var currentImage++;
                    $("#img").attr("src" , 'images/'+currentImage+'.jpg');
                }
                else{
                    var currentImage=1;
                    $("#img").attr("src" , 'images/'+currentImage+'.jpg');
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```